# Calling for even and odd figures

Tags: java

Write a method named hasAnOddDigit that returns whether any digit of a positive integer is odd. Your method should return true if the number has at least one odd digit and false if none of its digits are odd. 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8 are even digits, and 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 are odd digits.

For example, here are some calls to your method and their expected results:

Call    Value Returned
hasAnOddDigit(4822116)  true
hasAnOddDigit(2448) false
hasAnOddDigit(-7004)    true
You should not use a String to solve this problem.

This is my attempt at the question:

```
public boolean hasAnOddDigit(int num){
int number=0;

while (number > 0) {
    number= number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
}
    if(number%2==0 && num%2==0){
        return false;
    }else{
         return true;
    }


}
```

Called for hasAnOddDigit(4822116) and it gives me a false instead of true.

Comment: Try stepping through your code with a debugger. Don't just freakout and ask why it's not working, you'll never understand.

Comment: I dont have a debugger.Just doing random practices online.Try drawing it down to interpret it but still cannot get it.

Comment: Look at the first 2 lines inside your method.

Comment: @user2179615 `"I don't have a debugger"` - get one and learn how to use it. It's a very useful tool. I recommend an IDE with a debugger such as [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your method should check each digit as it goes through the loop, rather than waiting for the loop to complete before making its decision. Currently, the `while` loop runs the `number` down to zero, and only then tries to check the value. Naturally, by the time the loop is over, both values are zero, so the return is `false`.

```
public boolean hasAnOddDigit(int num){
    // You do not need to make a copy of num, because
    // of pass-by-value semantic: since num is a copy,
    // you can change it inside the method as you see fit.
    while (num > 0) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        if (digit % 2 == 1) return true;
        num /= 10;
    }
    // If we made it through the loop without hitting an odd digit,
    // all digits must be even
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive version which might be more intuitive for some.

```
private boolean hasAnOddDigit(int num) {
        if (num<10) {
            return num%2==0 ?  false :  true;
        } else {
            return check(num%10) || check (num/10);
        }
    }
```